# not sending correct link to set the password in registration email

Tags: user-registration, email-verification

it is a big problem. when a new user sign up in my website, as usual in wordpress, one email will be sent to him/her to be able to set him/her password.
the email will be sent but the link is incorrect. it is like so:

```
Username: username To set your password, visit the following address:  
http://end-eng.com/wp-login.php
```

as you see, the link is for login page, not for setting the password!!!

Comment: Now i display those table by HTML but maybe it will change in Future.

Comment: Well have you tried the code you posted?

Comment: @Jacob Peattie  Hi. no my friend. i am not sure about that

Comment: @JacobPeattie my friend. i can not ask question. and i edited my question! would you help?

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass the post id as parameter and check it will give the result you want 
in function.php

```
function tr_count($post_id){  
ob_start();  
the_content();  
$content = ob_get_clean();  
return substr_count($content, '<tr>');  
}
```

in single.php

```
echo tr_count(get_the_ID());
```